# Geany IDE code editor inserts value from GUI into the actual code itself

Tags: python, kivy, geany

Now, this appears to be really a strange phenomenon. I'm using Geany IDE to work with python and kivy. My kivy GUI has some TextInputs. When some text are inserted into those textinputs I see all those texts within my actual code itself being inserted randomly. App itself works pretty fine and no errors in functionality. But next time when the code is executed, the interpreter shows me all these random texts in my code which I will have to remove manually and then run the code again. Is that some IDE bug or am I doing something seriously wrong ?

Should I switch to some other IDE ? I'm working on a project in RPi and the code is getting considerably big.

Comment: Please give some materials to get a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.